# Switch to an "App" when viewing a custom visualforce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, app

I have an App configured (with my Logo setup) and the app has some standard tabs, etc.

I also have a button that the user can click from any Account record which takes them to a custom visualforce page I built.

When the go to this visualforce page, is it possible to switch them into the App context so that the logo will display in the upper left?

Comment: AFAIK, there's no way to do this reliably in Classic, and it's most likely blocked in Lightning anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have the following in your button URL:

```
/servlet/servlet.Integration?lid={yourAppId}&tsid={yourTabId}
```

replace the text in {} with your app id and your tab id
and make it "Display in existing window without sidebar or header"
here are some screenshots of my config, i tested and it worked

The Config: [image: The config]

The Account(Notice i'm on Sharing POC app): [image: The Accounts Page with Button]

The End Result(Notice i'm in different App, with the Test Tab highlighted): [image: After redirection]

Comment: If I do this - will the lid and tsid change when a customer installs my managed package? In other words, can I hard code these two values or do I need to dynamically SELECT them from the database?

Comment: i believe the values would change from one org to the other, so I'd say a custom label is what you need then reference that custom label, but you'll need to connect to the Metadata API to get the values of the Tab & App then set the Custom Label
PS. This additional bit wasn't mentioned in your original question, to get better answers try to give all the relative information.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. And I'm sorry for not putting in all the information.

Comment: I think this is no more working when I tested.. Can u please confirm ? I checked in both lightning and classic